# In search of a word this is in either in English or Latin

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

The thing is there might not be a word for it, but if there is I am looking for the exact word for it.

The meaning of the word would literally be 'Has no shadow' or 'Shadow-less.'

You might not say there is such a thing but fire nor plasma cast a visible shadow.

P.S. Although I do have the answer 'shadowless' in my question I am looking for a different word other then that.

Comment: Would 'transparent' not suffice?

Comment: @seagull Fire is not transparent. Anything that emits sufficient light itself does not cast a visible shadow.

Comment: What I think of transparent is to mean 'Not see though.' What I am looking for is for something that means it doesn't have a shadow

Comment: I mean 'Doesn't cast a shadow.'

Comment: See also: vampires.

Comment: Other than Shadowless, I can only think of _Soft Light_. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_light

Comment: Please do not use region tags like **american-english** when it makes no sense whatsoever to do so.

Comment: @tchrist, I should since I am looking for BOTH an american-English and Latin word to use for it.

Comment: No, you're looking for an _English_ word. The tag _american-english_ is for cases when it is important that there is a difference between what American, Canadian, British, Scottish, Irish, South African, Australian, or some other regional variant of English has, which is not the case here. Or at least, if you're specifically looking for a word that is unique to American English, you have not mentioned it at all in the question.

Comment: Then what tag should I use if I am saying English, but not specifying what type of English I am using?

Comment: @BlazeOfLight You shouldn't need a tag to indicate English at all - This is **E**LU; If you're getting answers in other languages, we're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a perfectly straightforward word for this in English, and you’ve even included it in your question: *shadowless*.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177226) defines *shadowless* as –

> 1. Casting no shadow.
> 2. Of a lamp or its furniture: So constructed as to cast no shadow.
> 3. Having no shadows on its surface; unsheltered from the sun. Of light, the sky, etc.: Unclouded.

The third of these meanings goes against the meaning you intend, of course; but the word is instantly recognisable and understandable, and though it’s rare, you should have no qualms about using it.

If you’re more interested in using a ‘Classical’ term, [Ancient Greek has *ἄσκιος*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)%2Fskios), which has the exact same duality in meaning: either ‘unclouded/unshadowed’ or ‘casting no shadow’.

If there were a Latin word, it might be expected to be something like **inumbralis*, but as far as I can tell, there isn’t. It would also be quite ambiguous in Latin, since *inumbrō* means ‘to overshadow’.

Comment: Janus, thanks for your remark, but I am just wondering is if there is an other word then shadowless that I can use?

Comment: None that I am aware of.

Comment: Damn, you actually did get to *Ascians*, which was what came to my mind.  Now I have nothing else to say. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could say *ascius* in Latin, which literally means *without shadow*;

Etymology
From Latin ascius (“without shadow”),
 from Ancient Greek ἄσκιος (áskios, “without shadow”), 
from ἀ- (a-, “not”) + σκιά (skiá, “shadow”)

Noun;
ascian (plural ascians or ascii)

person or thing without a shadow
person or thing found close to the Equator

Comment: No probs at all. Glad it helped. ☺